# java map with duplicate keys

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm creating a program that needs to store key-value pairs. The program needs to accept requests in the form of keys, and return the respective values.

The problem is that there are sometimes multiple values for each key, and the map class doesn't allow for duplicate keys.

The values are numbers, so I can't meaningfully concatenate the values like I would with strings.

Is there any elegant way of accounting for the fact that there can be more than one numerical value for each key? I want each number to be returned, not just one at random.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$ cat YourMap.java
public class YourMap extends HashMap<String, List<Integer>> {
    public void put(String key, Integer number) {
        List<Integer> current = get(key);
        if (current == null) {
            current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            super.put(key, current);
        }
        current.add(number);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        YourMap m = new YourMap();
        m.put("a", 1);
        m.put("a", 2);
        m.put("b", 3);
        for(Map.Entry e : m.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}

$ java map
b -> [3]
a -> [1, 2]
```

Comment: don't forget to put current into the map after you create it.

Comment: Ah, yea, doh. Should I mention the code was untested? :)

Comment: I've implemented this, but when I call the get() method, I always get null. Should we be overriding the get method? If so, how would that be done? If not, what should I do to make the get method return a non-null value? cheers.

Comment: @oadams: the code as originally posted would have acted this way -- it was missing the "super.put" line above. You probably don't have that line in your copy.

Comment: Use guava's MultiMap as @ErnestFriedman-Hill pointed out

Answer (score 11):

The structure you're looking for is called a "multimap". You can either use an ordinary map with ArrayLists as values, or you can use a multimap implementation. There's a nice one in Google's "guava" toolkit. See [here.](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Answer (score 4):

If you make the value a list then it will be able to store multiple values for a key

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```